# Find closest value in a Binary Search Tree - Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

My code is below creates a Binary Search Tree and then uses a recursive method to return the closest value. When I run this in debug mode I can see that it stores the correct value in the `closestValue` however, the terminal prints `None`.

what line of code do I need to edit so I can return the correct value?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
    self.value = value
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insert(self, value):
        n = Node(value)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = n
            return
        else:
            parent = self.head
            while parent != None:
                if parent.value < n.value:
                    if parent.right == None:
                        parent.right = n
                        break
                    else:
                        parent = parent.right

                elif parent.value > n.value:
                    if parent.left == None:
                        parent.left = n
                        break
                else:
                    parent = parent.left

            else:
                pass


    def findClosestValueInBST(self, target, closestValue):
        currentNode = self.head
        self.closest_helper(currentNode, target, closestValue)

    def closest_helper(self, currentNode, target, closestValue):
        if currentNode == None:
            return closestValue

        if abs(target - closestValue) > abs(target - currentNode.value):
            closestValue = currentNode.value
        if target < currentNode.value:
            return self.closest_helper(currentNode.left, target, closestValue)
        elif target > currentNode.value:
            return self.closest_helper(currentNode.right, target, closestValue)
    else:
        return closestValue


array = [10, 5, 15, 2, 7, 13, 22]
bst = BST()
for num in array:
    bst.insert(num)


print(bst.findClosestValueInBST(23, 100))
```

Comment: Perhaps `return` in `findClosestValueInBST`...

Comment: This worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add return in the function. Since you haven't returned anything yet, the terminal prints `None`

```
def findClosestValueInBST(self, target, closestValue):
        currentNode = self.head
        return self.closest_helper(currentNode, target, closestValue)
```